# How to add new css file for a module in Magento2?

Tags: module, magento2

I'm trying add custom css file for my module namely Magento_Hello in magento2. In the module I've created new page and trying to add new custom css to that page.

Here is what I have done in app/code/Magento/Hello/hello_index_index.xml. ('hello' is the frontName of my module)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Hello\Block\Hello" name="hello" template="success.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
    <referenceBlock name="head">
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Head\Css" name="magento-hello-css">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="file" xsi:type="string">Magento_Hello::css/custom.css</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</page>
```

I'have added the css here app\code\Magento\Hello\View\frontend\web\css\custom.css

But I'm getting the error in system.log which says `the 'magento-hello-css' element cannot be added as child to 'head', because the latter doesn't exist [] []`

What I'm doing wrong? Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the latest beta version for Magento 2 there is no more `head` block.
The head, content and other blocks are defined as containers.

should remove the `<referenceBlock name="head">` section and instead add this inside the `<head>` tag (where you added the page title)

```
<css src="Magento_Hello::css/custom.css"/>
```

so your `<head>` tag should look like this:

```
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <css src="Magento_Hello::css/custom.css"/>
</head>
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct way to do it? When I've tried this method Magento goes for ``server.tld/pub/static/frontend/Magento/theme/language_CODE/Namespace_Module/css/custom.css`` which doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. The static content files are deployed in the right place at runtime or by calling `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` in the command line

Comment: Interesting, though it didn't help for me, it deployed a whole bunch of files for en_US (though I'm using the sv_SE locale) and my CSS file isn't available for en_US or sv_SE. Seems deploying a module has become a lot more involved with Magento 2...

Comment: This does not work for me either, at least not in the admin panel ... Does anyone have idea why ? I've done this in my layout .xml for the page <head>
        <css src="Vendor_Gift::css/test.css"/> 
</head> And I've tried to put the test.css file in both folder - view/web/css or view/adminhtml/web/css - clear the cache and the pub/static, deployed static content after that - NOTHING ....

Comment: Thanks, it works!

Some hint for possible problems: Put your assets in `view/frontend/web` like:
`app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/view/frontend/web/css/styles.css`
`app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/view/frontend/web/js/scripts.js`