# How to add css to head via observer

Tags: magento2

In magento 1, I have used addCss function to add css file to head.

However, I don't see this function in magento 2.
 Can you help me?

Comment: Are you trying to add the the head of all pages?

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 has a quite different approach to CSS, where the Less pre-processor is an important part the play.

In layouts there you can add have a `<css>` element in `<head>`, so you do it via configuration rather than PHP code.

But there is also the whole Less infrastructure where maybe you want to use the _extend.less file to merge your CSS into the main CSS file generated rather than forcing the web browser to download an additional page. So I would suggest you also read up on Less support in Magento.

See also [How to add new css file for a module in Magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/59199/how-to-add-new-css-file-for-a-module-in-magento2)